# A batch file runs at startup won't delete itself using "del" command

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, startup

I have a batch file *.cmd that I cretaed in the location:

```
C:\Users\{User}\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\~\Startup"
```

to make it run on startup to execute a powershell script that in turn executes a program *.exe.

The whole thing should happen only once on a machine, it has to never get executed again at all, so it's a FIRST RUN thing.
That's why I am trying to get the initiating file "the .cmd batch file" to delete itself after everything's done the first time.

### Startup.cmd:

```
@echo off

PowerShell -Command "Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted" >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1
PowerShell C:\PowerShell.ps1 >> "%TEMP%\StartupLog.txt" 2>&1

del Startup.cmd
```

---

### PowerShell.ps1:

```
$Username = 'Administrator'
$Password = 'Password'
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username,$SecurePassword)

Start-Process powershell.exe  -Credential $Credential -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "(Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Windows\Somefolder\CLIAutomatedProcess.exe')"
```

The process that the powershell script executes is a CLI app that runs to configure some stuff then reboots the system to apply changes.

Everything seems to work as expected except for the `del Startup.cmd`, it doesn't seem to be deleting the batch file. I ran a test and had to remove the file manually. How can I make sure it deletes itself after first execution so it is only on First Boot?

Comment: Either it isn't executing with sufficient privileges, or it's not find the batch file (different working directory than the file location). Try `del %~pnx0`.

Comment: Woops, make that `%~dpnx0`, just in case the current drive got changed somewhere.

Comment: In the registry you can place some auto-start programs; there is also a `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\...\RunOnce` key that runs listed items once; perhaps this could be helpful...